# Linux kernel: fastest way to copy small amounts of data

Tags: memory, linux-kernel

I'm refactoring the kernel's LZO compression code.
It happens often that small bits of data is copied from one buffer to another.
The usual length of such a copy operation is either 4, 8, or 16 bytes long.

What's the best way to perform these operations? Is it memcpy or are there specific functions for these small buffer sizes that can make use of CPU opcodes in case they are supported?

Comment: memcpy is very efficient, direct assignment, probably a bit faster as the compiled code will be "smaller" (malloc has a few tests which it runs, while direct assignment doesn't). I would suggest however to use memcpy, not direct assignment which might break due to small endian, big endian, as well as 32bit/64bit

Comment: Before you start using very specific opcodes, you might want to make yourself aware that Linux runs on such diverse things a wristwatches, all the way up to big honkin' mainframes. If you're messing about with the kernel, you'll probably need to handle all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to perform these operation is with `mempcy`, because the compiler is able to implement them with direct assignments if the size is a constant.

Comment: In fact you're right. If the compiler does not support the optimization, it's also the kernel that optimizes memcpy for constant sizes: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/b3a3a9c441e2c8f6b6760de9331023a7906a4ac6/arch/x86/include/asm/string_32.h#L184